Nuclear winter and global warming
Nuclear winter is often described as a still, cold winter night. But what kind of atmospheric instability would cooled air and heated ocean give rise to?

I don't know where nuclear winter is "often described as a still, cold winter night", but in practice, in many parts of the world, winters are also the time of the most ferocious storms. For example, in most of Europe, winter storms are far stronger than ones in summer. Here where I live, in Colorado, winter storms bring howling winds. At the tops of mountains, where I spend a surprisingly large amount of my time, winter storms are ferocious -- much stronger than typical summer winds. So I don't think the association you mention is correct.
